# updating a document's complex property in DocumentDB in C#

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

When I make updates inside a property of SortedList type of a document (haven't checked other Dictionary / List types) Those updates are ignored by the serialization process (even by the ToString method of the object).

Example:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
public class BusinessStats : Document
{
    public BusinessStats()
    {
    }
    public BusinessStats(int businessId)
    {
        this.Id = businessId.ToString();
        Counts = new SortedList<int, int>();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Business id
    /// </summary>
    public override string Id
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Id;
        }

        set
        {
            base.Id = value;
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty()]
    public SortedList<int, int> Counts { get; set; }
}
public static class Test
{
    BusinessStats bizStats =    DocumentDB.Client.CreateDocumentQuery<BusinessStats>(DocumentDB.BusinessStats.SelfLink).Where(s => s.Id == p.BusinessId.ToString()).ToArray().FirstOrDefault();
        if (bizStats == null)
        {
            bizStats = new BusinessStats(p.BusinessId);
        }
}
if ( ! bizStats.Counts.ContainsKey(1))
        {
            bizStats.Counts.Add(1, 10);
        }
        else
        {
            bizStats.Counts[1] = bizStats.Counts[1] + 1;
        }

        var updateOperation = await DocumentDB.Client.UpsertDocumentAsync(DocumentDB.BusinessStats.DocumentsLink, bizStats);
```

First time this runs and inserts a proper Json, second time it reads the proper json, and deserialization goes well.
then, after it updates Counts[1] to be 11, it doesn't effect the ToString() and serialization of bizStats.

DocumentDB's .NET SDK makes me sad

Comment: Can you please try deriving from Resource instead of Document? I think some of the issues might be around how DocumentDB (JSON.NET) serializes DynamicObjects.

Comment: @AravindRamachandran Thank you for replying. In my quest for an answer I came around this explanation and tried it. it didn't help.
I guess complex documents should be handled with JS. Meanwhile I ran back to SQL server arms with that feature